# No value is still true in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check some data given by a dataset attribute, it can happen that the dataset is empty, if so I still need to skip with a if statement, but an empty dataset is still true, I have tried...null, undefined and they dont work.

So if there's no value present it should be false.

```
// false
<div data-value=""></div>

if($('div').data('value') !== ""){
   alert('hello ...world?')
}

//true
<div data-value="  "></div>

if($('div').data('value') !== ""){
   alert('hello ...world?')
}
```

Comment: trim the string first perhaps? Of course, a string containing spaces is not the same as an empty string. Trimming the string first removes space-characters (spaces, tabs, newlines...) in beginning and end.

Comment: I'm confused... Do you want the second one to be false, but it's still returning true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, `''` in javascript evaluates to false (an empty string). However `'  '` is a value, it is whitespace.

You can try trimming the string first:

```
// false
<div data-value="  "></div>

if($('div').data('value').trim() !== ""){
   alert('hello ...world?')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming and then checking for truthiness

```
$('div').each(function () {
    var data = $.trim($(this).data('value'));
    if (data) {
        alert('hello ...world?');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/qJXHr/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should test for exactly what you want. If you want to test if a string consists of something other than white space, consider:

```
if (/\S/.test($('div').data('value'))) {
  // value contains something other than white space
}
```